# SQL Join question

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables

1. **Links**
   Link ID
   Link Name
   GroupID (FK into Groups)
   SubGroupID (FK into Subgroups)
2. **Groups**
   GroupID
   GroupName
3. **SubGroup**
   SubGroupID
   SubGroupName
   GroupID (FK into Groups)

Every link needs to have a GroupID but teh SubGroupID is optional.  How do i write a SQL query to show:

**Links.LinkName, Groups.GroupName, SubGroup.SubGroupName**

For the records with no subgroup just put a blank entry in that field.  If i have 250 link rows, i should get back 250 reecords from this query.

Is there a way to do this in one query or do i need to do multiple queries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This assumes that there is at most only 1 subgroup per group.  if there are more, then you have the potential to get additional records.

```
select links.linkname, groups.groupname, subgroup.subgroupname
from links
  inner join groups on (links.groupid = groups.groupid)
  left outer join subgroup on (links.subgroupid = subgroup.subgroupid)
```

Comment: i keep getting this error when using your SQL:

syntax error (missing operator)  in query expression links.groupid = groups.groupid) left outer join subgroup on (links.subgroup = subgroupd.subgroup.id)

Comment: It looks like I misspelled linkname.  Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  links.linkname
  , groups.groupname
  , subgroup.groupname
FROM
  links 
  JOIN groups ON links.groupid = groups.groupid
  LEFT OUTER JOIN subgroups ON links.subgroupid = subgroup.subgroupid
```

(re-added to address OP's question)
incidentally, why not keep groups and subgroups in the same table, and use a self-referential join?

Akantro:

You'd have something like this:
    create table groups(
    groupid integer primary key,
    parentgroupid integer foreign key references groups (groupid),
    groupname varchar(50))

your query would then be

```
SELECT 
  links.linkname
  , groups.groupname
  , SUBGROUPS.groupname
FROM
  links 
  JOIN groups ON links.groupid = groups.groupid
  LEFT OUTER JOIN groups SUBGROUPS ON links.subgroupid = subgroup.groupid
```

there's no functional difference to keeping the tables like this, but the benefit is you only have to go to one place to edit the groups/subgroups

Comment: can you explain how you would do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Links.LinkName, Groups.GroupName, SubGroup.SubGroupName -- Will potentially be NULL
FROM Links
INNER JOIN Groups
    ON Group.GroupID = Links.GroupID
LEFT JOIN SubGroup
    ON SubGroup.SubGroupID = Links.SubGroupID
```

Answer (score 1):

You would use an Outer Join:

```
select Links.LinkName, Groups.GroupName, SubGroup.SubGroupName
from Links 
inner join Groups on Groups.GroupID = Links.GroupID
left outer join SubGroup on Links.SubGroupID = SubGroup.SubGroupID
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not too clear, but I think you want to get all rows including those that don't have a correspondent in the SubGroup table.

For this you can use LEFT JOIN, it will fetch NULLs if there are no matching rows.

Comment: Prody, I could be mistaken but I believe you have to specify an OUTER join to fetch nulls in case of no matching record.  You may want to revise your answer.

Comment: LEFT JOIN and LEFT OUTER JOIN are the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a LEFT OUTER JOIN on the SubGroup table like:

```
select
    l.LinkName,
    g.GroupName,
    s.SubGroupName
from
    Links l
'
    JOIN Group g
       on ( g.GroupId = l.GroupId)
'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SubGroup s
       on ( s.SubGroupId = l.SubGroupId )
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT LinkName, GroupName, SubGroupNamne
FROM Links INNER JOIN Groups ON LInks.GroupID = Groups.GroupID
    LEFT JOIN SubGroup ON Links.SubGroupID = SubGroup.SubGroupID
```

This will include rows that do not have a sub group.  That column will simply be NULL.

Answer (score 0):

```
select L1.LinkName, G1.GroupName, NVL(S1.SubGroupName,' ')
 from Links L1, Groups G1, SubGroup S1 
where L1.GroupID = G1.GroupID and
      L1.GroupID = S1.GroupID
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, try:

```
select a.linkname, b.groupname, c.subgroupname
from links a, groups b, subgroup c
where a.groupid = b.groupid
and a.subgroupid = c.subgroupid
and a.subgroupid is not null
union all
select a.linkname, b.groupname, '  '
from links a, groups b
where a.groupid = b.groupid
and a.subgroupid is null
```

I think that should work (it does in DB2 which is the DBMS I use most) - you'll need to adjust the spaces in the second select to match the subgroup.subgroupname size.

Answer (score 0):

Use a LEFT OUTER JOIN on the SubGroup table will give you all rows from the Links table and where a SubGroup exists will return that otherwise you see a NULL value.

```
SELECT L.LinkName, G.GroupName, S.SubGroupName
 FROM Links As L
  INNER JOIN Groups As G ON L.GroupID=G.GroupID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SubGroup S ON L.SubGroupID=S.SubGroupID
```

This does not check that your SubGroups.LinkID matches the Links.LinkID which should never happen but if you need to check this then add in another clause to the join:

```
SELECT L.LinkName, G.GroupName, S.SubGroupName
 FROM Links As L
  INNER JOIN Groups As G ON L.GroupID=G.GroupID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SubGroup S ON L.SubGroupID=S.SubGroupID AND L.GroupID=S.GroupID
```